# twitter_samples in both corpus and download

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to implement a basic twitter sentiment analysis project. For this, I import from a corpus twitter_samples as following

```
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
```

but it also needs to use the following command;

```
nltk.download('twitter_samples')
```

to work properly.

My intuition about this is that, the `twitter_samples` from `from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples` is a function and the `twitter_samples` in `nltk.download('twitter_samples')` is the dataset. Am I correct or is it something else? Please explain. Also is there any specific reason as to why the name `twitter_samples` is same in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for using same name is both the cases is that you have to download it only once. Post that you can directly use it with import statement.

nltk has huge number of offerings, all of them may not be required for everyone, hence you will have to download the stuff you want (only once per env), then use it using import statement.